# How to disable R from changing the "-" character into '.' character when writing to a file?

Tags: r

I want to write the results of a table into a file and names of my columns contain the '-' character, but when I write it to a file it replaces all the '-' by a '.'.

```
function(Result,Path)
{
  Num<-0
  for(i in 1:length(Result[,1]))
  {

    if(length(which([Result[i,]>0))>0)
    {
       temp<-which(Result[i,]>0)]
       val<-paste(names(temp),sep="\n")
       write(val,file=paste(Path,"/Result",Num,".txt",sep=""))
       Num<-Num+1
     }
  }
}
```

do any one know how to disable this option?

My column names are names of proteins some of them are written in this way YER060W-A

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you share the syntax you are using to write the file out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes special care to make such an entity. But then you can use the col.names argument and assign colnames(dfrm) to it.

```
> tst <- data.frame(`a-b`= letters[1:10], `1-2`=1:10, check.names=FALSE)
> colnames(tst)
[1] "a-b" "1-2"
> write.table(tst, file="tst.txt", col.names=colnames(tst) )
```

Pasted from my editor:

```
"a-b" "1-2"
"1" "a" 1
"2" "b" 2  snipped the rest...
```

No success with write.table? I see that write() doesn't have the same repertoire of options as write.table. Let's make an array (rather than a dataframe) with dim names having "-"'s:

```
DCtest <- array(1:27, c(3,3,3))
dimnames(DCtest) <- list(dim1 =c(a="a-b",b="b-c",c="c%d"), 
                         dim2=letters[4:6], 
                         dim3= letters[7:9])
```

One quick way to get output is just capture.output():

```
capture.output(DCtest, file="testm.txt")
```

testm.txt now looks like this in an editor:

```
, , dim3 = g

     dim2
dim1  d e f
  a-b 1 4 7
  b-c 2 5 8
  c%d 3 6 9

, , dim3 = h

     dim2
dim1   d  e  f
  a-b 10 13 16
  b-c 11 14 17
  c%d 12 15 18

, , dim3 = i

     dim2
dim1   d  e  f
  a-b 19 22 25
  b-c 20 23 26
  c%d 21 24 27
```

You also should not forget that capture output has an append= parameter if you wanted to append successive slices through an array.